# Replacing Mathematical Operators with Variable Java

Tags: java, variables, math, operators, calculator

Currently trying to do a reverse polish calculator for one of my Uni homework tasks.

I have the program working fine when using a bunch of if/else statements to work out which operator was typed in and do the mathematical operation normally like num1+num2.

This is beyond the homework task we were set but what I'm trying to do now is replace the operator with a variable for example: "`num1 + num2`" would become "`num1` *variable* `num2`" where variable equals "`+`" etc.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. You have to check for variable and then do it manually based on that.

Comment: FYI: Prefix notation ("Polish") is `+ 3 4`, Postfix notation ("Reverse Polish") is `3 4 +`, and Infix notation is `3 + 4`, so you want an **infix** calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in going beyond the scope of the training material, and assuming you've learned about interfaces already, I believe what you are looking for is a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) (that wikipedia article actually explains it good).

Basically, you create an interface `Expression` with a `double compute()` method. There will be two types of implementing classes:

- Operand: `Constant` and `Variable`.
- Operator: `Plus`, `Minus`, `Multiply`, `Divide`. Each will have two `Expression` fields: `left` and `right`.

Your text expression is then *parsed* into the expression tree:

```
// input: "num1 + num2 * 3"
// result expression tree will be built by parser using:
Expression a = new Variable("num1");
Expression b = new Variable("num2");
Expression c = new Constant(3);
Expression d = new Multiply(b, c);
Expression e = new Plus(a, d);

Map<String, Double> variables = /*defined elsewhere*/;
double result = e.compute(variables);
```

Your new assignment, should you choose to accept it, will be to write the expression classes and a parser to build the expression tree from a text expression.

Hope this will encourage you to go *way* beyond the training material, having some fun while playing.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Going to go try it now!

Comment: Andreas, nice solution. I would add that Expression are operands too (from a high abstract level point of view).

Comment: @Victor They are, which is why I mentioned `Constant` and `Variable` as two "operand" type implementation classes of `Expression`.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use a switch on String rather than if-then-else chain. Another way is to build a static final Map (E.g. HashMap) from String to Function. The strings are the operators. The Functions do the operation. In Java 8 you can give the functions as lambdas. I only have access through a phone right now so can't show code. Your question will be much better received if you add code showing what you mean.